# Swift : SLKTextViewController's left button is not viewed

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm using SLKTextViewController to build chat dockview with two buttons.

I want the left button with `UIPopOverController` for taking photos and so.

```
class Message: SLKTextViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
          self.textView.placeholder = "Message"
        self.textView.placeholderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        self.leftButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icn_upload"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.leftButton.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        self.rightButton.setTitle("Send", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.textInputbar.autoHideRightButton = true
        self.textInputbar.maxCharCount = 31
        self.textInputbar.counterStyle = SLKCounterStyle.Split
        self.typingIndicatorView.canResignByTouch = true
        self.bounces = true
        self.shakeToClearEnabled = true
        self.keyboardPanningEnabled = true
        self.inverted = false
```

I added that to make it appear but it didn't

```
        self.leftButton.hidden = false
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to display left button, just initial it.

```
self.leftButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("cameraPressed"), 
    forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.leftButton.setImage(UIImage.init(named:"CameraIcon"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Then you can add UIPopOverController in camearPressed function. (I would prefer UIAlertController style though)